# Movement of an inclined plane due to inertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, inertial-frames

[image]

Hello,
I tried reaching to the problem by thinking that since there are no non conservative forces acting on the system, Fnet = 0. So, m x g x sin30 = (m+M) x a' where a' is the horizontal acceleration towards right. But I was not sure because I felt like something is wrong.

Comment: The component of the normal force in the horizontal direction is the force that moves the wedge to the right.

Comment: The wedge and block do not have the same common acceleration

Comment: @MoziburUllah so, (mgsin30cos30)/(M+m) would be the acceleration of the wedge?

Comment: @Huzo: I would think so.

Comment: @MoziburUllah But then would this a' affect the time block reaches the bottom? Or would it be the same if the wedge was fixed?

Comment: @Huzo: I wouldn't have thought so as the vertical component of the normal force is only affected by gravity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding inclined plane acceleration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251985/finding-inclined-plane-acceleration)

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Comment: See also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/372144/26969) for potential duplicate